# What would cause ceiling lights in a circuit to stop working after the first one?

Tags: electrical, lighting, light-fixture, ceiling, recessed-lighting

enter image description hereSo, I have three recessed ceiling lights on a single switch.  The first ceiling light turns on, but the next two do not.  Because the lights downstream of light 1 don't work, that would suggest a problem between lights 1 and 2.  I completely uninstalled both lights and even inspected the junction boxes, but I couldn't find the problem.  I reinstalled both lights and the problem persisted.  I doubt there is anything between junction box 1 and 2, so what could the problem be?

Picture Link:  https://imgur.com/a/vM7eh5C

Comment: It might just mean the lights burned out.  Check if the light bulbs work in the first one, and then check the wire connections in the first light.  all electrical connections need to be tight.

Comment: Please [edit] to describe your process for inspecting the junction boxes. 9,999 times out of 1000 that's where your problem is, so if you didn't physically check both switched hot and neutral connections in each box, go back and do that. Looking in the box without doing anything else does not solve the problem...

Comment: I swapped bulbs, so it's not the bulbs.  I've also checked and rechecked the connections.  

As for the junction boxes, I opened them up, removed the wire nuts, exposed new copper on each wire and re-did the connections before adding the wire nuts back on.

Comment: Did these lights work before and just stop, or is this a new circuit wired up?  Pictures of the wires are connected in junction/light boxes and switch will help to see if wires are connected right.

Comment: The lights worked before.  I'll go take pictures now...

Comment: Here are the pictures - https://imgur.com/a/vM7eh5C

Comment: Looking at the pictures, it looks like you have mostly solid copper and some stranded **aluminum** mixed in. If that is stranded aluminum (as opposed to stranded copper, that would be fine) then you have some major problems as aluminum and copper require special procedures/equipment to connect properly.

Comment: I agree that it's copper with some stranded aluminum.  But it's the original wiring, so I hope the builders did whatever they needed to do to make it safe.  And, the lights were working just a few days ago.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

> *I agree that it's copper with some stranded aluminum.*

##### STOP. RIGHT. NOW.

Copper and aluminum connected together can lead to problems. Burn your house down type of problems.

Not *all* situations are bad. Copper wires connected to aluminum connections in circuit breaker panels are fine. But copper wire to aluminum wire or aluminum wire to devices (receptacles, light fixtures, etc.) that are not designed for use with aluminum wire are a big **NO WAY**.

If it is practical, the best thing to do is to replace the aluminum wires. That may be easy or it may be very hard. If it is not practical, then you need connectors designed for that use. In a quick search, the first product I found was for solid or stranded copper but only solid aluminum.

So figure out what you've got, especially where you have aluminum (pictures are not clear which segments are which) and then we can figure out a solution.

Comment: Thank you manassehkatz.  I'll replace them immediately.